# What index(es) should I create on Oracle tables based on how I query them?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have two tables with many columns that I need to create index(es) on based on the most common ways the tables will be filtered when queried.

The primary key of table 1 is columns A, B, C, D, and E.

The primary key of table 2 is columns A, B, C, and F.

Table 2 will be left joined to table 1 on columns A, B, C, and F.

Both tables already have an index on the primary key and I also created an index on table 1 using columns A, B, C, and F, since it is a foreign key.

When the tables are queried, the filter will always consist of columns A, B, and C, and one of the other columns in either table 1 or 2.

Columns A, B, and C together have several hundred combinations.

The other columns that the fourth column in the filter could be are as follows:

- D (table 1): Millions of possible values
- F (both tables): Millions of possible values
- G (table 1): Millions of possible values
- H (table 1): 9 possible values
- I (table 1): Hundreds of possible values
- J (table 2): Millions of possible values
- K (table 2): Millions of possible values
- L (table 2): Thousands of possible values
- M (table 2): Hundreds of possible values
- N (table 2): 14 possible values

I'm trying to figure out what the best strategy is for creating indexes on these tables.  Can I create one additional index for each table with all the columns from that table that would potentially be used in the filter?  Is there some optimal way to create a few indexes with different combinations of the above columns based on the number of unique values?  And for each index that I create, how do I know what the best order is to put the columns in?

One thing I did already try was to create an index for every possible way the tables could be queried.  But I quickly learned this isn't feasible when it dramatically slowed down the amount of time it takes to insert data into the tables and eventually ran out of UNDO tablespace.

Comment: 'How do I know what column order' - oracle will be able to use an index from left to right, if only parts of the index are used in the query.. an index on A,B,C,D,E (in that order) can be used to answer a query with a where clause containing only a,b,c

Comment: Thanks.  So that would mean the indexes I already have will take care of the scenarios when the fourth column is either D or F.

Comment: If the fourth column is D then the index can be used for A,B,C,D. If the fourth column is F it may be that the index is used for only A,B,C. Index use is something the optimizer evaluates on a case by case - it sometimes has a cost (because then the row has to be retrieved) that makes the optimiser give up. It may be, if your query was 'select d e where a b c f' that the index would be used because it can also answer the select without hitting the row, or it may be that oracle knows it will return so many rows that the indirection of the index is a waste, and just hit the table

Comment: The most critical thing you need to remember is to try to have as few index that cover as many of your queries as possible and arrange the index to cover all queries. An index on BCDAEF can answer a query on ABCD and BCD but probably won't answer a query on ABCF. It might be that you can add junk clauses DE even if you don't need them, to get the index used. For more in depth, read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/160649/composite-indexes-most-selective-column-first

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to drop all the indexes except those needed by the data model (i.e. on pk and fk).

Then I'd try to get a representative test load (easier said then done, I know).

Now you can use Oracle's [SQL Access Advisor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/sql-access-advisor.html#GUID-BBEB9848-36CF-4416-9330-2AFD5879B565) to recommend the indexes that provide some benefit.